# Twilio / TwiML on iOS - Using Enqueue and Dial

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, enqueue

Basically, I am creating an iOS app that will Dial a phone number in my office when certain button is tapped. This is working fine, but now I want to have a music file played while waiting for the phone to be picked up.

Knowing that Dial cannot use a music file to replace the default wait tone, I was guided to use Enqueue's waitURL. However, I am lost on how to Dequeue so to start the Dial. This is how the whole TwiML looks right now, and it plays the whole song without dialing in:

```
<Response>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="waitMusic.xml">office</Enqueue>
    <Dial callerId="+12345678910">
        <Number >999-999-9999</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

waitMusic.xml is simply:

```
<Response>
  <play>slowrock.mp3</play>
</Response>
```

Is it not possible to use this TwiML?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't use `<Dial>` and `<Enqueue>` like that together. Here's what you need to do.

When the user taps the button have them make the call and return just the `<Enqueue>` in the TwiML response.

```
<Response>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="waitMusic.xml">office</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

And in that response also [kick off a call to the number you want to dial using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls). When that call is answered, Twilio will request some TwiML, you should return a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) with a nested [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue) which will pop the top caller off of the queue and connect them to the person on the phone.

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Queue>office</Queue>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

You may need to do a bit more work to ensure you don't end up with anyone stuck in the queue, but that should get you started.